# Difference between { this.handleCreateNote } and this.handleCreateNote () in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I want to know the difference between `{ this.handleCreateNote }` and `this.handleCreateNote()`

```
  handleCreateNote = () => {
    let todos = [...this.state.todos];
    todos.push({
      id: todos.length,
      text: this.state.notetext,
      completed: false
    });
    this.setState({ todos: todos }, () => {
      console.log(this.state);
    });
    this.handleClose();
  };
```

Code

```
<TextField
    name="notetext"
    hintText="Note"
    style={{ width: "48%", float: "left", height: 48 }}
    defaultValue={this.state.noteVal}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    onKeyPress={ev => {
      console.log(`Pressed keyCode ${ev.key}`);
      if (ev.key === "Enter") {
        console.log("adf");
        this.handleCreateNote(); ---> here it doesn't call this.handleCreateNote; 
        ev.preventDefault();
      }
    }}
  />

  <div
    style={{
      width: "4%",
      height: "1",
      float: "left",
      visibility: "hidden"
    }}
  />

  <FlatButton
    label={strings.create_note}
    style={{ width: "48%", height: 48, float: "left" }}
    onTouchTap={this.handleCreateNote}
  />
```

Comment: Please, define "does not work".

Comment: @Sulthan it doesn't call `handleCreateNote`

Comment: Does it print "adf" to the console?

Comment: @Sulthan Yep...

Comment: If it doesn't crash then the method is probably called. Did you try to print `this.handleCreateNote` to the console?

Comment: @Sulthan Yes, it is not calling. It is calling when I write `this.handleCreateNote();` Is there any difference between them ?

Comment: Nope, only when the method is used in `onTouchTap` you will get some additional parameters.

Comment: I was asking about printing the literal method `console.log(this.handleCreateNote)` without calling that method. Just to see what's there. Did you try to put a breakpoint there and check what the debugger is doing?

Comment: It prints function body `function () {
      console.log("hey");
      var todos = [].concat(_toConsumableArray(_this2.state.todos));
      todos.push({
        id: todos.length,
        text: _this2.state.notetext,
        completed…`

Comment: Then I am pretty sure the function should be called when you append `()`. It's possible you have a hidden crash somewhere. Just put a breakpoint there and step through the code.

Comment: @Sulthan Yep It is calling when I append `()`, but not if I don't append `()` Let me check how I can debug in VSCode

Comment: If it's get called, what is the problem?

Comment: @Sulthan I mean what is the difference between `{ this.handleCreateNote }` and `this.handleCreateNote()` in ReactJS. Is there any difference ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I finally understood the confusion.

In `{ this.handleCreateNote }` you are passing a function which is then called by the event handler. You are not calling that function, React is calling it.

In `this.handleCreateNote()` you are calling the function by yourself. That's why `()` has to be there. Always when a function is called, the parenthesis are needed.

Compare:

```
const myFunction = this.handleCreateNote; // we are saving the reference to a function
myFunction(); // we are calling that function
```

which is the same as

```
this.handleCreateNote();
```

However, when using the handler you are doing only the first step. The second step is done by the event handler.